# Is it possible to create connection object inside a method using annotation

Tags: java, jboss, annotations

I am using jboss 7.0 application server. I am creating connection object using annotation as follows

```
@Resource(java:jboss/datasource/exampleDS)
Datasource datasource;
```

I have given annotation outside the method. Is it possible to declare annotation inside the method like

```
public void getConnectionObject(){

@Resource(java:jboss/datasource/exampleDS)
Datasource datasource;

}
```

As I need to pass the datasource value dynamically to the annotation from the method argument. Can I declare annotation inside the method. Please help me.

Comment: You cannot generally do this, since annotations are generally a compile-time phenomenon. There should be a different way to get an appropriate `Datasource` such as via a constructor or factory.

Answer (score 0):

You can't set annotations in the code of a method, only atop of it or atop of the class to set it generally for the whole class.

Also it is possible to do something like this:

```
@AnnotationPossible
class Sample {
    @AnnotationPossible SampleService sampleSrv; 

    @AnnotationPossible
    public void test(@AnnotationPossible String test){
        @NOTPOSSIBLE
    }
}
```

Where I wrote NOTPOSSIBLE you can't use annotations.